# Three.js shadow map stripes in each light (now simplified, and with jsfiddle!)

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create, modify and update (directional only for now) lights and shadowmaps dynamically. The light, shadow and shadow camera helper gets updated correctly as I move the light around or change shadow properties, except from the light's point of view, everything behind the origin (0,0,0) is shadowed for no apparent reason.

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPduM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaZqn.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Iz6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEpCM.jpg (new, with spotlight)

You can see a scene with car and a piece of ground, they belong to a geometry imported with ColladaLoader. The problem is with shadowmapping, the car throws shadow correctly, but there are stripy shadows on the ground even though there is nothing else than the car obscuring light.

If I add more similar lights, they also have the same 4 stripes. They also appear with spotlight. If I change shadow map resolution, the stripes' size changes relative to each other, but there seems to be always four of them, spaced from center to both directions.

EDIT: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cL3hX/1/ There shouldn't be any shadows in the scene, unless some new geometry is introduced inside the shadow camera frustum.

Couple of notes on the fiddle:

- I have r55, but the demo is r54 because jsfiddle apparently does not yet have r55.
- I could only reproduce this with a Collada file. So it probably has something to do with the model. I created a simple cube in Sketchup 8, and tried to export it with various collada options.
- In the JSFiddle I could only reproduce the bug with a file exported with "doublesided faces" -setting enabled. In my own application code, I do have the same bug on models created with or without that setting enabled, but in the fiddle, the bug seems to be triggered only when "doublesided faces" are exported. Anyway I do need to somehow show backsides of faces, because the tool I'm developing must work with Sketchup exports, and it's very hard to make models in Sketchup without having a mess of frontsides/backsides visible.
- The very simple Collada file is included in the JSFiddle as javascript variable. Here's a download link for the same file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14489569/shadowmapdemo.dae

Comment: Try giving your plane depth by replacing it with a thin `CubeGeometry`. Try adjusting `light.shadowBias`. Try setting `renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceNone` or `THREE.CullFaceBack`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately none of these made difference. I tried with different values of shadowbias, they needed to be very very low for shadows to work at all, but it did not help either. I made yet another screenshot, this time the ground is 0.1 units thick (10cm), and has additional shapes for testing shadows: http://i.imgur.com/brKwCof.jpg

Comment: Also the text labels (sprites) and virtual camera geometries are rendered on a separate render call. Removing those did not help. I also tried removing the helper sphere to no effect.

Comment: Remove the car and *everything unrelated* from your code, and create a live example that demonstrates the problem (jsfiddle.net). use r.55.

Comment: So far I have been unable to create a simple example / fiddle that has this problem, they work correctly so far. I will try more later, the brain does not work anymore. I got a hunch it might have something to do with materials and updating / changing them, but I can't even remember what/why I was thinking that.

Comment: @WestLangley I finally have a (non-)working JSFiddle :) Edited the post with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Collada model.

Your "plane" is actually multiple coplanar faces back-to-back in a single geometry.

It's no wonder there are artifacts.

Replace it with a THREE.CubeGeometry.

Comment: Those models are what I need to work with. I can control the export settings, but then I'll loose the backfaces, which in Sketchup can be different material (likely that's why the setting exist). Is there anything else I can do to work around the problem? If not in shadowmap setup, maybe detecting the coplanar faces and doing.... something? I'll accept this if nothing better comes up, but replacing with CubeGeometry is not possible for me.

Comment: To be honest, I put considerable effort into tracking this down for you, and explained to you what was causing the problem: you have to remove the back-to-back faces. If you do not want to do that, or can't, then the solution is up to you.

Comment: Sorry if my response came up sounding unappreciative, I'm not. You have helped tremendously, and now that it is narrowed down to geometry thanks to you, I will try to come up with a solution other than having different geometry (fixing geometries in javascript if possible, or getting the shadowmapping to work with the messed up geometry as is, or maybe waiting for WebGLDeferredRenderer to be more ready and see if it's different there). Not sure which direction I should try.